# Issues with ofstream

Tags: c++

I'm finishing this code but I'm wondering why I can't output an archive with ofstream.

What did I do wrong?

The problem is in the line 61. Compiler says: error, 'struct std::stringstream' has no member named aux4.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>



using namespace std;


class  validate { 
       public:
              int aa, mm , dd ;
              string guy;
       public:
              validate ( int x, int y, int z){
                      aa=x; mm=y; dd=z;
              }
       bool check ( int aa, int mm, int dd){
            if ( aa >0){
               if( mm == 01 || mm== 03 || mm == 05 || mm == 07 || mm == 08.0 || mm == 10 || mm == 12){
                   return dd <=31;
                   }
               else if ( mm == 04 || mm == 06 || mm == 09.0 || mm == 11){
                    return dd <=30;
                    }
               else {
                    return dd <=28;
               }
            }
       }
};

int main (){
    int aa, mm, dd, key;
    string name, date, aux1, aux2, aux3;
    stringstream aux4;
    do {

        cout<<"Name:"<<endl;
        cin>>name;
        cout<<"Enter date of birth:"<<endl;
        cin>>date;

        aux1= date.substr(6,9); 
        aa = atoi(aux1.c_str());
        aa=2012-aa;

        aux2= date.substr(3,4);
        aux2=aux2.substr(0,2);
        mm = atoi(aux2.c_str());

        aux3= date.substr(0,2);
        dd = atoi(aux3.c_str());

        aux4 << dd << mm << ".txt";
        ofstream file(aux4.aux4().c_str(), fstream ::app);
        file<<aa<<"years"<<name<<endl;
        file.close();



        cout<<"Enter key != 0 if you want to continue ( Ideally press 1):"<<endl;
        cin>>key;

    }while ( key != 0);
    cout<<"Thanks! End of line."<<endl;

    system ("PAUSE");
    return 0;
};
```

Comment: What's with this one? `mm == 08.0`, as well as the 09.0 below. Are they just there to try to circumvent the fact that octal literals can't contain 8s or 9s? The proper circumvention would be not using octal literals in the first place if you need an 8 or 9 in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler pointed you straight to the problem.  You probably meant this:

```
aux4.str().c_str()
```

instead of:

```
aux4.aux4().c_str()
```

`std::stringstream` doesn't have an `aux4()` method.